# How set the host and the port of a Flask app in config module?

Tags: python, flask

To execute an application in Flask we use the method

```
app.run ()
```

In this method we can pass configuration parameters, among them:

```
host, port, debug
```

By default the Flask application is executed in

```
host = localhost
port = 5000
```

So, if we want to change that configuration, we pass it to the run method

```
app.run (host = "10.100.100.10", port = 9566)
```

In the case of wanting to have different configurations for your application (either, production, development, testing) you must define a configuration dictionary, something like this:

```
app.config.update (
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = '...'
)
```

Or more specified create a config module:

```
class Base(object):
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = "Shhhh is a secret"
    SERVER_NAME="localhost:5000"

class Develop(Base):
    SERVER_NAME="10.100.100.10:5001"
```

Reading (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/) I found this attribute:

```
SERVER_NAME
```

Quoting the Flask documentation:

> the name and port number of the server. Required for subdomain support
>   (e.g .: 'myapp.dev:5000') Note that localhost does not support
>   subdomains so setting this to "localhost" does not help. Setting to
>   SERVER_NAME also by default enables URL generation without a request
>   context but with an application context.

This attribute should change the host and the port.

I defined this then:

```
app.config.update (
    DEBUG = True,
    SERVER_NAME = "10.100.100.10:6500"
)

and

class Base(object):
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = "Shhhh is a secret"
    SERVER_NAME="localhost:5000"

class Develop(Base):
    SERVER_NAME="10.100.100.10:5001"

and

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config.Develop')
```

As a result it keeps showing when executing the application:

```
Running in 127.0.0.1:5000
```

**How can I make my application run on another host and port without having to use parameters in the run method?**

Comment: If you're starting your flask application from the command line with the `flask` command, you have to either set the `FLASK_RUN_PORT` environment variable to the port you want your application to run on (e.g. `export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000`) or pass the port as an argument like that: `flask run --port 8000`. Have a look here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#setting-command-options

Comment: as of flask 1.1.x this is working :  `SERVER_NAME = '0.0.0.0:8000'`
Put it inside Develop class and check.

Answer (score 10):

why do you need to set the port outside the run method? Don't forget such a deployment is only for development purposes. in your built in server but you may change the port like that: somewhere you should have something like `app.run()`
I am posting a runnable code, its port set to 5001. I hope it helps.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5001)
```

Comment: This still launches on port 5000 (not 5001) for me on flask 1.0.2

Comment: `app.run` not meant for production

Comment: it is still running on port 5000!